# How do I show the whole root polynomial below in python?

Tags: calculator, sympy, polynomials

How do I show the 5 root polynomials below in python?
I want it to show every root.

```
x = Symbol('x')
det_p = x**5 - 5*x**3 + 5*x + 2
eq1 = Eq(det_p,0)
b_solve = solve(eq1)

print('Energias dos Orbitais: ', [s.evalf() for s in b_solve])
```

Results:
Energias dos Orbitais:  [-2.00000000000000, -0.618033988749895, 1.61803398874989]

Comment: You got all roots. `1/2 - sqrt(5)/2` and `1/2 + sqrt(5)/2` are both double roots.   `det_p.factor()` is `(x + 2)*(x**2 - x - 1)**2`.  `sympy.plot(det_p, (x, -2.1, 2))` shows how the function touches the x-axis at both points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with polynomials and want to see all roots in their multiplicity then you can use either roots, which gives a dict showing multiplicity or `Poly.all_roots` which gives a list of possibly repeated roots:

```
In [3]: roots(det_p)
Out[3]: 
⎧       1   √5     1   √5   ⎫
⎨-2: 1, ─ - ──: 2, ─ + ──: 2⎬
⎩       2   2      2   2    ⎭

In [4]: Poly(det_p, x).all_roots()
Out[4]: 
⎡    1   √5  1   √5  1   √5  1   √5⎤
⎢-2, ─ - ──, ─ - ──, ─ + ──, ─ + ──⎥
⎣    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2 ⎦
```

Relevant docs:

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#symbolic-root-finding-algorithms

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.Poly.all_roots